# Why isn't UserForm loading?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code. The form doesn't initialise. I've checked and the name, not the caption, is correct.

It gives me an error saying it can't find the specified object on `formSelectSheet.Show`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public sheetsToHideSize As Integer
Public sheetsToHide() As String

Sub HideSelectedSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'stores all worksheet names in an array
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sheetsToHideSize = sheetsToHideSize + 1
        ReDim Preserve sheetsToHide(sheetsToHideSize)
        sheetsToHide(sheetsToHideSize) = ws.Name
    Next ws
    
    formSelectSheet.Show
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your form/module broke. Try exporting form and import to new file.